# how to find what languages are loaded into EnterpriseDB?

Tags: postgresql, metadata, plpgsql, spl, enterprisedb

How can I find what languages have been loaded into EnterpriseDB(PL/pgsql, SPL, Java)? EnterpriseDB is built on top of PostgreSQL if anyone knows of a way to find the loaded languages on PostgreSQL. It should work the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The installed languages are registered in `pl_language`, e.g.:

```
steve@steve@[local] =# select * from pg_language;
 lanname  | lanowner | lanispl | lanpltrusted | lanplcallfoid | lanvalidator | lanacl
----------+----------+---------+--------------+---------------+--------------+--------
 internal |       10 | f       | f            |             0 |         2246 |
 c        |       10 | f       | f            |             0 |         2247 |
 sql      |       10 | f       | t            |             0 |         2248 |
 plpgsql  |       10 | t       | t            |         73259 |        73260 |
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the ["pg_language"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-language.html) system catalogue (hopefully EDB is not that different from Postgres).